# How to teach emacs remote compilation?

Tags: emacs, compilation, ssh

I use sshfs + emacs to remotely work on a project.
But I can't "M-X compile, make" since make is remote.
What is the easiest way to solve it so that emacs can take me to the first error?
(I have only ssh access to the machine)

TRAMP seems to be an overkill.
No, I don't want to give up having emacs locally.

Comment: [Similar questions with answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=emacs+remote+compilation)

Comment: Most of them talk about TRAMP while I want something much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like M-x compile RET ssh remotehost cd project/dir\; make RET